# Завершение пакета файла через npm после выполнения скрипта при участии пакета nodemon (git-cmd)

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, nodemon

Если в кратце:

"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",

"compress:css": "node-sass css/style.comp.css css/style.compress.css --output-style compressed",

"build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass compress:css",

"no-install-scss-compile": "npx nodemon -e scss -x "npx node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css"",

"no-install-scss-compress": "npx nodemon -e scss -x "npx node-sass css/style.comp.css css/style.compress.css --output-style compressed"",

"no-install-build": "--"

Попытка выполнить пакеты последовательно без их локальной установки.
Что не получается:
Остановить скрипты с nodemon после разового выполнения.
Схлопнуть по аналогии ctrl+c или как при базовом их выполнении без nodemon.

(Пробовал использовать флаги самого nodemon по типу --exit. Также пробовал process.exit(0), exit 0 т.к запускаюсь на Windows. Скрипт не останавливается.)

Вторым этапом стоит задача выполнить все одним билдом. Кто-то вообще знает, является ли это возможным. Может само использование nodemon для данной задачи не совсем корректно. Т.к его первоначальное назначение совсем не об этом. Кто ответил, ответит спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте process.exit(0) для отслеживания process.on('exit', function (code) {return console.log(code)} )

Comment: а для чего в вашей команде участвует nodemon?

Comment: nörbörnën - для запуска пакетов без их локальной установки.

Comment: Rudi -  как корректно добавить process.exit(0) или exit 0 например в данный скрипт:
"no-install-scss-compile": "npx nodemon -e scss -x "npx node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css""

Comment: Возможно вам поможет установка флага `--quit` для `nodemon`  "no-install-scss-compile": "npx nodemon --quit -e scss -x \"npx node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css\"" Флаг говрит nodemon завершить выполнение после первого изменения, которое отслеживается.

Comment: @eloiola в этом "скрипте" вы же используете вызов команды npx, которая и делает "запуск пакетов без их локальной установки". в чем смысл `npx nodemon -e scss -x "npx ..."`, почему не `npx node-sass css/style.comp.css css/style.compress.css --output-style compressed`?

Comment: – nörbörnën это работает, спасибо. Ошибочно считал что npx это не сделает самостоятельно. – 
– Rudi к сожалению --quit не работает. Но в любом случае спасибо за ответ.